# Index apparently not used on a group by select

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this table:

```
code|c1|c2|ins_date
```

And this index

```
ins_date asc, code
```

My query is:

```
select code, count(*), to_date('24-06-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from T1 
        where ins_date=to_date('24-06-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') 
         group by code;
```

This query is super slow as there are millions record.
Anyway, judging by the execution plan:

```
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |        |     4 |    48 |    11  (10)| 00:00:01|
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |        |     4 |    48 |    11  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1     |  1390 | 16680 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

It would seem that my index on ins_date is not used, but a whole full table access is perfomed!
Why is that? By removing that group by statement:

```
select count(*), to_date('24-06-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from T1 
        where ins_date=to_date('24-06-2015','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

I instead get:

```
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| T1_INSD |  1390 | 11120 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `ins_date` column?

Comment: Kind of hard to say without seeing your exact index DDL and your statistics and your various CBO settings.    What happens when you use ins_date in the column list instead of to_date? So select ins_date,code,count(*) with the group by,

Comment: are the code and ins_date columns set to allow nulls?

Comment: @Boneist that is a good point and would certainly explain the behavior. Time for my coffee I guess :-)

Comment: ins_date is a date, while code is a number. Neither of them are allowed to be null.

Comment: @TheMadDBA You'd think that if code was nullable, then the fact that ins_date is filtered on a specific date that it would still be able to use the index, but I've seen Oracle chose to FTS because of the nullable column before now!

Comment: @Phate you mean they've both got not null constraints on them?

Comment: yes, there is a not null for both of them...

Comment: What happens when you select ins_date and code for a specific date without the group by. How many rows does it return? How many rows in your table?

Comment: Mad you solved it...it returns 1390 rows out of...1390! I have to try adding some new rows but I guess it is just an optimization by oracle. Strangely enough query still is very slow.

Comment: what happens if you add ins_date into the group by?

Comment: For now it just still uses full table scan.

Comment: Trying to narrow it down since something is obviously wrong... What happens when you add IS NOT NULL for both columns? How many rows does the CBO think you have in that table? (select ins_date,code with no where)

Comment: For a tiny table with just 1390 rows Oracle will most probably never use an index scan. Given that your table has only 4 columns, probably all rows are spread over something like 10 database blocks. Retrieving all of them in one go is faster than doing an index lookup for each and every rows (which requires at least 3 I/O operation **per row**)

Comment: That is entirely true... I think there is some confusion here though. They initially said the table had millions of rows. If it only has 1390 rows then Oracle is doing exactly what it should do.

Comment: Yes sorry it was supposed to have but then some cleaning procedure removed the most of rows (cleaning is performed per day basis) and so it ended up with poor row number

Answer (score 1):

The impression of Oracle (based on you table statistics) is as follows:

1) there are 1390 records with ins_date=to_date('24-06-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') and

2) there is a cost of 10 (aprox. blocks I/O) to read a table with FULL SCAN

```
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1     |  1390 | 16680 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
                                       ^^^^^             ^^
```

I can only speculate, but very probable scenario is as follows:

1) You populated the table with 1390 records each with ins_date=to_date('24-06-2015','dd-mm-yyyy')

2) you (or Oracle) gathered table statistics

3) you added "millions or records"

This leads exactly to your execution plans. Note that before the step 3) the shown execution plans are the correct and perform best!

The remedy is easy - re-gather the table statistics and repeat your queries.